# onload event throws 'object expected' error

Tags: javascript, onload-event

Whenever I use the  event, i get a javascript error saying "Object expected" pointing to the line containing the onload event. Here is a simple representation of my webpage.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='myScript.js'>
    //script containing doSomething()
  </script>
</head>
<body onload = "doSomething('stringArg', 0);"> //<--does not execute, throws error, EDITED for proper quotation

//body of site

<script type='text/javascript'>
  //test call
  doSomething('stringArg', 0); //<--executes just fine, no errors
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

You are using single quotes for everything so the parser thinks your attribute ends after `'doSomething('`

Use double quotes to avoid confusion

```
<body onload = "doSomething('stringArg', 0);">
```

Hopefully not to confuse you, but in javascript, quotes are more or less interchangeable so you could also swap them:

```
<body onload = 'doSomething("stringArg", 0);'>
```

They just can't all be the same.

Comment: sorry about that, my code actually has the correct quotation, I just flubbed it up when writing the post. I've editted the above post to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error (because of the single quotes being used for both the string literal and the attribute value).  Try this:

```
<body onload = "doSomething('stringArg', 0);">
```